# How do I only optimise storage for videos over 1 year old?

Tags: ios, backup, photos, video, jailbreak

This can be using Jailbreak modifications or using a feature available in iOS.

I have a 64GB iPhone 6S that has over 40GB of photos and videos on it - most of that being videos. However, I am quickly running out of usable storage. I want to be able to still access new photos and videos but I want videos older than a year to be 'optimised'.

Is there any way to do this either using Jailbreak tweaks or iOS features? If not how could I build a tweak to do this?

Comment: Hi Evan - great details. Do you mind if I make an answer explaining why I think you should optimize using the system settings and not worry about some time restriction on the build in optimization using iCloud? Perhaps you have disregarded that and could edit that research / clause to your question if that’s the case. Either way +1 Welcome to Ask Different.

Comment: That is fine bmike. I am open to all solutions or advice on how to solve or approach my problem.

Comment: Videos are already compressed, hence they can not be "optimized". The only thing that is possible is to reencode them by loosing quality (e.g. reduce resolution or increase the compression) or use a different video codec that requires more CPU/GPU but creates smaller videos. But AFAIR the videos already use HEVC/H265 compression which is quite good algorithm considering quality and file size.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in iOS feature that allows you to do exactly this. Nor do I know of any jailbreak tweak that enables this feature.

Building such a tweak would require software development experience along with specific knowledge about the iCloud Photos metadata storage.